# Page reload after ajax request for delete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a webpage which displays all the records of a table with a checkbox infront of them. I can select the boxes and then make a ajax request for deleting them.

The deletion works fine. but even after refreshing it shows deleted records.

**Things I used for redirection**

-

- window.location.href = '/current_page';
- location.reload(true)

I used them success callback. If i click on browser then it works.

Comment: *"but even after refreshing it shows deleted records."* Sounds like your server side is not deleting the records. *"If i click on browser then it works"* Not sure what that's supposed to mean.

Comment: Do you have any database that would be storing these records? Or it's just a static client-side app?

Comment: ajax request  deletes the records from db successfully and in success call back, i refresh the page so that deleted records are not displayed. But old records are there on page. if i go the browser and click the refresh button. All the records are displayed which are yet to be deleted correctly

Answer (score 1):

Try to use anchor to redirect by call the below function :

```
function redirectFunc(){
  var link = document.createElement('a');
    // set your page url 
    link.href = "url";
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Math.random for generate hash and put this in href of page. This well the page reload with no cache. The cache look adress page for query of content in cache.

Look this example:

```js
function reloadWithNoCache(){
  window.location = window.location.href + '?eraseCache=' + Math.random();
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Refresh With No Cache" onclick="reloadWithNoCache()"/>
```

Comment: I tried this approach but still same records exist on page. Only if a click on the browser for refresh then it works fine.

Comment: <meta HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">

Comment: I tried this but no success, is there some of way of complete page reload

Comment: The query uses ajax too?

Comment: Try window.location.hash( "new-url-hash" ) before reload page

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to do is an hacky way.
If you are trying to refresh the page then using location reload or anyother way then no point making an ajax call, you can simply make a delete call and target the page to a new url just like initial request.

This solution would be a bit bigger but scalable.
I hope you might be rendering the initial table with some front end templating supplying some data as a model to the table. So on success of ajax request instead of reloading the page, try to reconstruct the DOM with the rest over data.

ex : model = {1,2,3}
table contains 1 2 3

after delete update the model to 1 3 (if you have deleted 2)
and call a render method of table with new model {1,3} erasing the old table. If you feel the data is too heavy (unless its too big) that it might really nag the user with performance you can go with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

No need for page refresh. You can delete the rows in the table using jQuery in your ajax success callback.